# Package 'org.json' is declared in module 'json', but module 'com.example.demo' does not read it - JavaFX & Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

In a project using Maven & JavaFX, I'm trying to add this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

I did that - I reloaded my maven changes (using intellij), but I still can't use this package.

When I wrote this in my code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I've gotten this error

```
Package 'org.json' is declared in module 'json', but module 'com.example.demo' does not read it
```

And I don't understand why. I thought I might need to add it in module-info.java, but after some googling I think that I don't, because in that file I have to specify the dependencies for the JavaFX.

So... what does that error mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your `module-info.java`:

```
requires json;
```

To understand what it means, see:

- [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).